# Send a number via TCP IP in C#

Tags: tcp, ip

I want to send a number in Integer via TCP IP. I save a data in `Send_data` as a `Integer`'s number.

I can't change it to a `string` or `char[]` in order to send it. I only receive a space in Client when I run this code.

This is my code:

```
NetworkStream clientStream = MyClient.GetStream();
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(Send_data[0]);
clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
clientStream.Flush();
```

Comment: What is the value in `Send_data[0]` ?

Answer (score 0):

tcp client declaration and connection:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("IP_address"), port);
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();            
client.Connect(endPoint);
```

NetworkStream  declaration:

```
NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream();
```

BinaryFormatter for serilazation

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                                    //int goes here
formatter.Serialize(networkStream , Send_data);
```